# SQL database structure for week schedule

Tags: mysql, sql, calendar

I've been looking for an answer for the following question, but I didn't find anything on it.

I would like to make a SQL database where I can store data per day (Mon-Sun), per hour (every 15 minutes). It's sort of an overview from Monday to Sunday only from the previous week, where I can add data per 15mins.

If handling a lot of data (read several 100k rows). Would it be better to make tables per day and then have columns per 15 minutes?

Comment: Storing energy data from a smart meter by any chance?

Comment: No, it would not make sense to break down tables.  mysql is perfectly adept at quickly handling hundreds of thousands of rows.  Especially as narrow as you seem to be defining your table.  Are you trying to pre-generate the time information?

Comment: Oh god no....do not make tables per day.  Fewer tables the better, unless you are hitting hundreds of millions of rows, mysql will be fine with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just have a table that takes the data at the 15 minute interval with a timestamp.

So only 3 columns (user, data, timestamp). The timestamp could be in seconds/milliseconds/nano what ever format you want.

Once displaying the data you can compute what week its in on the "fly".

Comment: I don't even need to know what week it's in, it's just to compare day's of the week. The data will be filled in every 15 mins per day.

Comment: It's not for energy data for a smart meter, but it's a good example.
The table could be used to keep an average 'energy used'. It would update evere monday at every interval, in that way you can compare the current energy use with the average